# Getting href value during route change in Angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, routes

I'm building an angular application and I use this piece of code to check for authentication and other stuff during route change:

```
run(['$rootScope', '$location', 'Session', function ($rootScope, $location, Session) {
$rootScope.$on('$routeChangeStart', function (event, next) {

        if (Session.userId != null && next.$$route.originalPath.indexOf('login') > 0){
            console.log('already logged, redirect to appointments');
            $location.path('/appointments');
        }

        if (next.data.needAuth) {
            if (Session.userId == null){
                console.log('DENY');
                event.preventDefault();
                $location.path('/login');
            }
        }
        else {
            console.log('ALLOW');
        }
    });
}]).
```

The problem is that I use some tab in my html code that looks like this:

```
          <li role="presentation"><a href="#tab1" aria-controls="home" role="tab" data-toggle="tab"> <span class="icon s7-smile"></span></a></li>
          <li role="presentation"><a href="#tab4" aria-controls="settings" role="tab" data-toggle="tab"> <span class="icon s7-ticket"></span></a></li>
          <li role="presentation"><a href="#tab3" aria-controls="messages" role="tab" data-toggle="tab"> <span class="icon s7-help2"></span></a></li>
```

The result is that when I press them, the tab changes but also the redirect is triggered. There is a way I can get the value of href and do something like:

```
if (href.value.indexOf("tab") > 0)
     //do nothing
```

Comment: Isn't this something where providers / interceptors come in?

Comment: Can you explain yourself better? I don't understand what do you mean :(

Comment: nevermind, try using `event.stopPropagation()` instead of prevendDefault

Answer (score 0):

You can override the href using directive

```
app.directive('href', function () {
        return {
            restrict: 'A',
            priority:100,
            compile: function (element, attrs) {
                if (attrs.href && attrs.href.indexOf('tab') > 0) {
                    element.removeAttr('href'); // do nothing
                }
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: Thanks I added your code and now the redirect is not triggered. The problem is that I can't change tab anymore!

Comment: you have to add condition based on that you should play with href attribute, not for all cases

Comment: you can put your `run` block logic here only

Answer (score 0):

Ok so I solved this way: I deleted the default redirect:

```
  //$routeProvider.otherwise({redirectTo: '/login'});
```

and I inserted this condition on the routeChangeStart listener:

```
    if (typeof(next) !== 'undefined'){
        // old code
    } else {
        event.preventDefault();
    }
```